# null checkbox selections from Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, checkbox, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a list of people, represented with checkboxes, in my HTML form. When the user selects some of those people, and submits the form, my controller receives a List of `null` values for those selections, instead of the ID values in the HTML form. I think my binding result is misconfigured somehow.

[image: demo]

My HTML:

```
<fieldset id="covered_deps">
 <legend>Covered Dependents</legend>
  <label class="col-xs-4"></label>
  <ul class="col-xs-8" th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('oa.dependents')} ? has-error">

    <li class="col-xs-8 checkbox" th:each="dep, stat : ${session.submission.uso.peopleNotOrgs()}"><input type="checkbox"
        th:checked="*{oa.containsCoveredDependent('__${dep.id}__')}" th:name="oa.dependents" th:value="${dep.id}" /> <label
        th:text="${dep.getSimpleDisplayName()}">Jr</label></li>
  </ul>
<span class="help-block" th:errors="*{oa.dependents}">[error]</span></fieldset>
```

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/obli", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String updateObli(@Valid @ModelAttribute("obli") Obligation obli, BindingResult br, Model model, HttpSession session) { ...
```

Another method in my controller.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpSession session) {

    // obligation recipient [obligee]
    binder.registerCustomEditor(PersonOrOrg.class, new PersonOrOrgPropertyEditor(session));

    binder.registerCustomEditor(Payee.class, new PayeePropertyEditor(session));

    // covered dependents & obligor
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Person.class, new PersonPropertyEditor(session));
}
```

The weird thing is this: I have another collection of people represented with checkboxes in the form, just above this fieldset. That higher fieldset is working perfectly. It uses the same controller methods because it is in the same HTML form. When I compare the rendered HTML source for these two fieldsets, they are nearly identical.

My Spring Boot parent version is "1.3.7.RELEASE", which uses Thymeleaf "2.1.5.RELEASE".

Can I force Thymeleaf or SpringMVC to write warnings to a log file when it fails to bind attributes/properties of a nested form object?

My entire html can be seen here:

[editObli.html](http://pastebin.com/C0CA7Zna)

I should also mention the object graph.  The form operates on an "Obligation" object.  The Obligation class has two important member fields, SupportPayee and ObligationAugmentation.  SupportPayee has a List of Payee objects.  ObligationAugmentation has a List of Person objects to represent covered dependents.  The Payee class has a String id member field.  The Person class also has a String id member field but inherits it from the abstract super class it extends.  I suspect that SpringMVC cannot bind to the id in the abstract super class but I have no idea how to test that suspicion.  The code for the SupportPayee works great and the code for the ObligationAugmentation does not.

Below is a screenshot of the Network tab in developer tools of Chrome.  The highlighted values were my selections.

[image]

Comment: can you post your whole html page?

Comment: @Periklis, yes, I can but it's big and ugly.  I'll try.

Comment: Can you post body of request from `developer tools` after posting your form?
Are there `ids` present of this collection?

Comment: @yami, yes, in developer tools, under the Network tab in Chrome, I can see the id values I selected and submitted.  I'll try to include a screenshot of that.